# Trigger coverage in after Update

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

I am stuck in the test class for the trigger (after update). Sometimes its shows coverage of 37%. Now its shows 0%.I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
 if(trigger.isafter && trigger.isupdate){
        if(!checkRecursive.recordsInTrigger.containsAll(Trigger.newMap.keySet())) {
            checkRecursive.recordsInTrigger.addAll(Trigger.newMap.keySet());
            
            for(Opportunity opp:oppList) { 
                
                if(opp.Template__c != null && opp.Language__c != null){
                    // New chanes  9/6/2022
                    if(opp.Email_Sending_Option__c == 'Send via Past'){
                        if(trigger.oldMap.get(Opp.Id).Email_Sending_Option__c != trigger.newMap.get(Opp.Id).Email_Sending_Option__c ||
                           trigger.oldMap.get(Opp.Id).Language__c             != trigger.newMap.get(Opp.Id).Language__c||
                           trigger.oldMap.get(Opp.Id).Template__c             != trigger.newMap.get(Opp.Id).Template__c){
                               
                               if(trigger.oldMap.get(Opp.Id).Email_Sending_Option__c == 'Send Later'){
                                   string schJobName = opp.id;
                                   List<CronTrigger> jobsToAbort = [SELECT ID, CronExpression, CronJobDetail.Name,
                                                                    CronJobDetailId, EndTime, NextFireTime,
                                                                    PreviousFireTime, StartTime, State,TimesTriggered FROM 
                                                                    CronTrigger Where CronJobDetail.Name =: schJobName];
                                   if(!jobsToAbort.isempty()){
                                       for(CronTrigger cJob: jobsToAbort){
                                           System.abortJob(cJob.Id);
                                       }
                                   }
                                   
                               }
                               
                               ID jobID = System.enqueueJob(new saveTemplate(oppList));
                               system.debug('ID job ' + jobID);
                               
                           }
                    }
          
                    if(opp.Email_Sending_Option__c == 'Send Now'){
                        if(trigger.oldMap.get(Opp.Id).Email_Sending_Option__c != trigger.newMap.get(Opp.Id).Email_Sending_Option__c ||
                           trigger.oldMap.get(Opp.Id).Language__c             != trigger.newMap.get(Opp.Id).Language__c||
                           trigger.oldMap.get(Opp.Id).Template__c             != trigger.newMap.get(Opp.Id).Template__c){
                               opp.Email_Date__c = date.today();
                               opp.Email_Status__c = 'Email Sent';
                               checkUpdate.add(opp);
                               
                               
                           }
                    }
                    else if (opp.Email_Sending_Option__c == 'Send Later'){
                        try{
                            if(opp.Email_Date__c > date.today()){                 
                                if(trigger.oldMap.get(Opp.Id).Email_Sending_Option__c != trigger.newMap.get(Opp.Id).Email_Sending_Option__c ||
                                   trigger.oldMap.get(Opp.Id).Language__c             != trigger.newMap.get(Opp.Id).Language__c ||
                                   trigger.oldMap.get(Opp.Id).Template__c             != trigger.newMap.get(Opp.Id).Template__c ||
                                   trigger.oldMap.get(Opp.Id).Email_Date__c           != trigger.newMap.get(Opp.Id).Email_Date__c){
                                                              opp.Email_Status__c      = 'Email Not Sent';
                                                              String sDay              = String.valueof(opp.Email_Date__c.day());        
                                                              String sHour             = String.valueof(opp.Email_Date__c.format('kk'));        
                                                              String sMinute           = String.valueof(opp.Email_Date__c.format('mm'));      
                                                              String sMonth            = String.valueof(opp.Email_Date__c.month());        
                                                              String sYear             = String.valueof(opp.Email_Date__c.year());        
                                                              String CRON_EXP          = '0 '+sMinute+' '+sHour+' '+sDay+' '+sMonth+' ? '+sYear;
                                                              system.debug(CRON_EXP);
                                                              string schJobName        = opp.id;
                                  List<CronTrigger> jobsToAbort = [SELECT ID, CronExpression, CronJobDetail.Name,
                                                                        CronJobDetailId, EndTime, NextFireTime,
                                                                        PreviousFireTime, StartTime, State,TimesTriggered
                                                                        FROM CronTrigger Where CronJobDetail.Name =: schJobName];
                                       if(!jobsToAbort.isempty()){
                                           for(CronTrigger cJob: jobsToAbort){
                                               System.abortJob(cJob.Id);
                                           }
                                       }
                                       //    System.schedule(schJobName,CRON_EXP, new scheduledEmailLater(opp.Template__c+'.pdf',opp.Email__c,opp.Id,opp.Template__c,opp.Language__c));
                                       System.schedule(schJobName,CRON_EXP, new scheduledEmailLater(oppList));  
                                   }
                            }
                            else{
                                
                                Trigger.new[0].addError('Email date should not less then  today');
                       }
                        } 
                        catch(Exception e) {
                            opp.addError(e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
```

Test class

```
@isTest
public class SendEmailTest {
    static testMethod void testOpp() {
        Account testAcct = new Account (Name = 'My Test Account');
        insert testAcct;
        
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(
            Name = 'Test',
            AccountId = testAcct.id,
            CloseDate = date.today().addMonths(12),            
            StageName = 'Sourcing Demand',
            Email__c = 'test@gmail.com' ,             
            Email_Sending_Option__c =  'Send Later',
            Language__c = 'English',
            Template__c = 'In Memory of',
            Email_Date__c = date.today().addMonths(2)
        );
        
        insert opp;
        
         opp.Template__c = 'Estate Succession';
         opp.Email_Sending_Option__c =  'Send Now';
        
        
        update opp;
```

Comment: thanks for your response. But i think it answered my question. Actually updation is not working in my test class. this the problem

Answer (score 0):

I'll make an informed guess that the issue is with these lines at the top of the trigger handler

```
if(!checkRecursive.recordsInTrigger.containsAll(Trigger.newMap.keySet())) {
        checkRecursive.recordsInTrigger.addAll(Trigger.newMap.keySet());
```

Because your testmethod is doing both Opportunity insert and update in the same transaction, any static variables you set in that transaction during `insert` will persist through to the `update`.

You may need to clear the recursion control static variable between insert and update in your testmethod - or, use smarter recursion control that is sensitive to insert versus update events

Comment: i agree with your point.  but How to solve it Can you please??

Comment: I provided two ideas.  Try them and if still issues, edit your OP